# What is Jenkins' Tools "Subdirectory of extracted archive" for?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I've added the [SonarQube extension](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/jenkins-extension-sonarqube/) to Jenkins but I still have to specify [where it gets downloaded from](https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-5.0.1.3006-linux.zip). This works fine, but the location of the download isn't being added to my `PATH`. I've seen comments in [other posts](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-client/) that suggest you have to set the "Subdirectory of extracted archive" to the path of the executable after it's unzipped. I've tried this but it doesn't make a difference to the PATH:[image]

Comment: In order to use it in your jobs, in your job you need to 
**[ X ] Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment**, then invoke the sonarscanner in the build steps.  The "sub-directory of the extracted archive" depends on what is is the tarball; it does not have to come from sonarsource and may change depending on OS, etc., but why not choose "Install from Maven Central"?

Comment: Because it doesn't work: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/adding-sonarqube-to-a-c-build-on-jenkins/99478/10

Comment: I do involve SonarScanner in the build step, but I have to set the PATH myself. I'm trying to understand how Jenkins can set this automatically.

Comment: **[ X ] Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment,**

Comment: My project in Jenkins doesn't have a **Build Environment** section, I think that's only for Maven builds.